# Why is two hours the maximum acceptable offset for Bitcoin blocks?

Tags: protocol, timestamp, block-validity

As far as I understand, Bitcoin transactions include a timestamp, but the only requirement is that they don't differ for more than two hours.

But why two hours? For computers that are constantly synced via NTP, two hours seem like a very big difference. I would expect that a difference of 10 minutes should be enough.

Or, if this is about time zones and summer time, shouldn't they be using UTC time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transactions don't have a timestamp. *Blocks* have a timestamp. The difference is important, because the block timestamp on some of the blocks changes the difficulty.

> Why is the maximum difference two hours?

It's not particularly important to have very accurate timestamps. Timestamps have two uses:

- [Difficulty retargeting](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/how-is-difficulty-calculated)
- Calculating progress of synchronization. If the blockchain started in 2009, and the last block you saw was made in 2012, then you're about halfway done.

> Or, if this is about time zones and summer time, shouldn't they be using UTC time?

They do. Of course, not all systems are set up correctly. For example, imagine a system that doesn't use NTP. The user doesn't know how to set up DST correctly, so they move their computer's clock forward/backward an hour every spring/fall.