# A problem on difficulty equation

Tags: difficulty, mastering-bitcoin

When I read this book [Master Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook), I have a problem in understanding the "Difficulty" in Chapter 8.

There is a equation of difficulty:

`New Difficulty = Old Difficulty * (Actual Time of Last 2016 Blocks / 20160 minutes)`

I feel confused.
According to the formula, if **Actual Time** was longer than **20160 minutes**, the **New Difficulty** would be bigger than **Old Difficulty**, and then **Actual Time** would be longer and longer.

It looks very strange. For me the equation should be:

`New Difficulty = Old Difficulty * (20160 minutes / Actual Time of Last 2016 Blocks)`

However, I found this fomula is consistent with that in bitcoin code.

```
unsigned int CalculateNextWorkRequired(const CBlockIndex* pindexLast, int64_t nFirstBlockTime, const Consensus::Params& params)
{
    if (params.fPowNoRetargeting)
        return pindexLast->nBits;

    // Limit adjustment step
    int64_t nActualTimespan = pindexLast->GetBlockTime() - nFirstBlockTime;
    if (nActualTimespan < params.nPowTargetTimespan/4)
        nActualTimespan = params.nPowTargetTimespan/4;
    if (nActualTimespan > params.nPowTargetTimespan*4)
        nActualTimespan = params.nPowTargetTimespan*4;

    // Retarget
    const arith_uint256 bnPowLimit = UintToArith256(params.powLimit);
    arith_uint256 bnNew;
    bnNew.SetCompact(pindexLast->nBits);
    bnNew *= nActualTimespan;
    bnNew /= params.nPowTargetTimespan;

    if (bnNew > bnPowLimit)
        bnNew = bnPowLimit;

    return bnNew.GetCompact();
}
```

Then I found this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5840/51036).
This is what I understand, but why it is different from the equation of the book and the code.

**update**

I think this was just an ambiguous expression.
The better expression should be:

`New Difficulty Target = Old Difficulty Target * (Actual Time of Last 2016 Blocks / 20160 minutes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're citing does not actually deal with difficulty. It deals with *targets*. The target is the maximum 256-bit value than the block hash is allowed to have.

The difficulty is defined as **2^208 * 65535 / target**.

As for the book, that looks wrong indeed.

Comment: Thanks for answer, as you said, the description of the book is wrong?

Comment: The book is wrong.