# How to calculate DGB-Groestl difficulties?

Tags: difficulty

I'm new here. 
I want to know how mining difficulties are calculated, specifically for **DGB-Groestl**, which uses **Myriad-Groestl** algorithm.

I might understand how to calculate the Bitcoin difficulties from this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/how-is-difficulty-calculated) but having hard time to calculate difficulties for other algos. I hope someone could help. What are the details/data that I need to calculate and what is its formula.

Thanks in advance to all. :)